# csv files and appending data to a list

Tags: python

I was wondering if there is a way to append data to a list but only the last 5 decimal places of the data that is read from the csv file then appended to a list.

Below is a sample of the code I have down to the point of appending the csv file to a list.  At the moment all the vales within the csv file (which have up to 10 decimal places) are appended, but I only need first 5 places.  Is this possible ?

```
def main():
    welcome_message()
    user_input()

def welcome_message():
#will eventually display a welcome message and programme description

def user_input():
    my_file = open('TestData.csv', 'rU')
    calculation(my_file)

def calculation(my_file):
    my_data = csv.reader(my_file)
    next(my_data)                       
    my_list = []                        

    for row in my_data:
       my_list.append(row)              #append the csv data to a list
```

Comment: Can you use something simple like `my_list.append("{0:.5f}".format(row))`?

Answer (score 1):

You could use format to limit the decimal places:

https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language

```
def main():
    welcome_message()
    user_input()

def welcome_message():
#will eventually display a welcome message and programme description

def user_input():
    my_file = open('TestData.csv', 'rU')
    calculation(my_file)

def calculation(my_file):
    my_data = csv.reader(my_file)
    next(my_data)                       
    my_list = []                        

    for row in my_data:
       x = '{:.5f}'.format(float(row)) 
       my_list.append(x)              #append the csv data to a list
```

Note that I'm appending strings to the list. If you want them to be floats, just cast them as float(x).